# cannot save raw plug.vim file

Tags: plugin-system, macos

MacOS, I am trying to save plug.vim file by:

1. navigate to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
2. Using ***save file as*** option to save plug.vim to this location /usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload

But this file would be removed as soon as it was downloaded, why?

Comment: This sounds more like a macOS problem? I think this would be better asked at SuperUser or the Apple site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about macOS rather than Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't alter the base vim configuration.  Instead, you should put this in your user's vim configuration directory, which on macOS would be `~/.vim` i.e. `~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim`.

To answer you actual question as to why it is removed as soon as it is downloaded, how are you trying to write to that directory?  As you mention "save file as" I can infer that this is from a browser as your user; `/usr/share` is only writeable to the root user.

Comment: thanks, the reason I was not saving it to ~/.vim is: it is empty. I was not sure if I should create an autoload repo or not. I got it now.